# Django Static Files - CSS File Won't Load

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django, and am trying to load a static css file.
I have seen the other questions and read the docs, but I am still unable to see the problem.
I am using Django 1.11.

Here is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url 
from django.contrib import admin

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from . import views

urlpatterns = [ 
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

My settings.py (only the part to do with static files):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/static/")

STATICFILES_DIRS = ( 
    STATIC_ROOT,        
)
```

And the part of my template where I try and load the files:
    {% load static %}

Whenever I load the index.html template, the following error messages are displayed by my console:

```
core.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at core.js:5
localhost/:12 GET http://localhost:8000/static/css/homepage.css 
localhost/:11 GET http://localhost:8000/static/css/horz-navbar.css 
localhost/:10 GET http://localhost:8000/static/css/fonts.css 
localhost/:13 GET http://localhost:8000/static/css/style.css
```

Here is the file directory structure:

```
mysite
  db.sqlite3
  manage.py
  mysite
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    views.py
    wsgi.py
  static
    admin
    css
      fonts.css
      horz-navbar.css
      homepage.css
      style.css
  templates
    index.html
```

So Django doesn't seem to recognize that the files exist, I have checked and made sure that the files exist on my computer, and I'm not sure if this was needed, but I have also run `python manage.py collectstatic`

Please tell me if you need anymore information.

Comment: Can you also paste the file directory structure in your question?

Comment: I have added a directory structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `STATIC_ROOT` into another name and then update your `STATICFILES_DIR`.  Something like this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_files')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `"{% static "css/fonts.css" %}"` with `"{% static 'css/fonts.css' %}"`. There's a mismatch between quotations.

Comment: I have done this, but the files still won't load. I get the same errors.